# A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session (Bi-directional many-to-one association)

Tags: java, spring, oracle, hibernate, jpa

I have had this problem for days, I have tried all the solutions. So I ask here maybe for more help.
I have a parent class and a child class connected in a bidirectional way. I enclose the code:

```
 @Entity
 @Table(name="PARENT")
 public class Parent implements Serializable {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="PARENT_SEQ")
    @SequenceGenerator(name="PARENT_ID_GENERATOR", allocationSize = 1, sequenceName="PARENT_SEQ")
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="parent", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Child> childList;

    //getter and setter ......
```

and this child:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="CHILD")
public class Child implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="CHILD_SEQ")
    @SequenceGenerator(name="CHILD_ID_GENERATOR", allocationSize = 1, sequenceName="CHILD_SEQ")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name="NAME")
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ID_CHILD")
    private Parent parent;

    //getter and setter ......
```

The moment I do this :

```
     @Autowired
     ParentService parentService;

     ......

     Parent parent = new Parent();
     //various parent setters
     List<Child> childList= new ArrayList<Child>();
            for (Employee employee: listEmployee.getEmployee()) {
                Child child = new Child();
                child.setNome(employee.getNome());
                childList.add(child)
                }
    parent.setChildList(childList)
    parentService.save(parent);
```

I get this error:

```
Caused by: javax.persistence.EntityExistsException: A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session
```

This my Service:

```
@Autowired
ParentRepository parentRepository;

.......

@Transactional
public void save(Parent parent) {
    parentRepository.save(parent);
}
```

It sounds like a cascade problem, but if I change with MERGE, my parent saves me, but not my child.

This is my sequence, the same for both, changing only the name:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE  "CHILD_SEQ"  MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 1000000000000000000000000000 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 41 CACHE 20 NOORDER  NOCYCLE ;
```

Thanks to anyone who can help me.

Comment: Have you tried to set the `Child.parent` property to the `Parent` entity?

Comment: yes i try, but doesn't work

Comment: Usually, I'm caught by this error when I load an entity by ID, and in the same transaction, I try to save the another entity with the same ID. Consider for example, load an entity `A`, clone it, and try to save it again.